# sending email using smtplib and SSL but receiver is no receiving it

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, smtplib

I am trying to send email from one email to another using smtplib and ssl. It's showing delivered, but there is no email at receiver end. I am trying two different codes:

Code 1:

```
import smtplib, ssl

port = 465
smtp_server = "myserver.com"
sender_email = "sender@myserver.com"
receiver_email = "receiver@gmail.com" 
password = "mypassword"
message = """\
Subject: Hi there

This message is sent from Python."""
try:
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context=context) as server:
        server.login(sender_email, password)
        server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
        print("Sent..")
except:
    print("Error!!")
```

code 2:

```
import smtplib
import os.path

from email.mime.text import MIMEText

msg = MIMEText("")

msg['Subject'] = "Hi there, This message is sent from Python."

s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("myserver.com:465")
s.login("sender@myserver.com","mypassword")
s.sendmail("sender@myserver.com","receiver@gmail.com", msg.as_string())
s.quit()
print("done")
```

Can not find the problem. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The `sendmail` method is a low level method that assumes that the message text is correctly formatted. And your messages do not contain the usual `To:` and `From:` headers.

The `send_message` method uses an `EmailMessage` and formats it correctly, so it can be easier to use. I would advise to change your code to:

```
port = 465
smtp_server = "myserver.com"
password = "mypassword"

msg = MIMEText("This message is sent from Python.")
msg['Subject'] = "Hi there"
msg['From'] = "sender@myserver.com"
msg['To'] = "receiver@gmail.com" 

try:
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context=context) as server:
        server.login(sender_email, password)
        server.send_message(msg)
        print("Sent..")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But for some reason still not getting the mail receiver end. Can there be any other thing?

Comment: If the server accepted it, yet it does not reach the recipient mailbox, you should ask the server admin if it can check the server logs. Maybe you could try to first send the message to a local mailbox.

Comment: There is no mail in the sent box in the server. wired. Don't know what to do.